# Using already initialised mailadapter in Parse server CloudCode

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mailgun, parse-server

With parse-server 2.2.6, how would one use the SimpleMailgunAdapter in cloud code?

I initialize my parseserver like this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  appName: 'AppName',
  publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
        fromAddress: 'mymail@mail.com',
        apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
        domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN
    }
  }
});
```

This is working (I.e. the verification emails are getting sent)

Now I want to send email from cloud code, without creating a new SimpleMailgunAdapter.

What I'm using today:

```
var SimpleMailgunAdapter = require('parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter');

  var adapter = SimpleMailgunAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
    domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
    fromAddress: 'mymail@email.com'
  })
```

This is working. But I feel that the best way would be to just fetch the already initialised mail adapter from my parse-instance. But I don't know how to do that. Would that be considered best practice, or can I stick with my solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mailgun to send emails from your cloud code.

First you need to install the npm module [https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js]

by using this command:

npm install mailgun-js --save

then update your server (Im using AWS elasticbeanstalk)

then on your main.js file, initialize mailgun by

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: 'XXX', domain: 'XXX.com'});
```

then create a cloud code function

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmail", function(request, response) {

    console.log("sendEmail " + new Date());


    var emailBody = request.params.emailBody;
    var emailSubject = request.params.emailSubject;
    var fromName = request.params.fromName;
    var fromEmail = request.params.fromEmail;
    var toEmail = request.params.toEmail;
    var toName = request.params.toName;

    var fromString = fromName + " <"+fromEmail+">";
    var toString = toName + " <"+toEmail+">"

    console.log("emailBody " + emailBody);
    console.log("emailSubject " + emailSubject);
    console.log("fromName " + fromName);
    console.log("fromEmail " + fromEmail);
    console.log("toEmail " + toEmail);
    console.log("toName " + toName);    

    var data = {
        from: fromString,
        to: toString,
        subject: emailSubject,
        html: emailBody
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("got an error in sendEmail: " + error);
            response.error(err);
        }else {
            console.log("email sent to " + toEmail + " " + new Date());
            response.success("Email sent!");
        }
    });
});
```